# Spotify Play button

Tags: html, button, widget, playback, spotify

Just looking for some clarification with the new play button.  I notice that when you hit play on the widget, it plays the song in the actual spotify app.  Does that mean you need spotify to use the widget?  What happens if you hit play and you don't have spotify? Do you have plans to make the widget independent of the app?

Comment: I doubt Stack Overflow (you're referring to "you") is going to do *anything* to the widget.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Play Button works in a very similar way to Spotify's Facebook integration:

- The tracks are played in the Spotify client.
- If the Spotify client isn't running, it'll be launched.
- If it isn't installed, the user will be led through a streamlined install process.

At the moment, this is required simply because without it we'd have to write a Spotify client in JavaScript, which is 1) hard and 2) served in plain text, which isn't really something we want to do! :-)